# Adding my post into Top Answers on my profile returns the error: "The link you provided does not lead to a StackExchange answer. Please try again."

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, hyperlinks, error-message, user-experience

I am trying to add one of my posts to my Stack Overflow CV (even though it is useless/downvoted), but it doesn't allow me and shows the following error message:

> The link you provided does not lead to a StackExchange answer. Please try again.

This is the post which I wanted to add: [IIFE with unary operator: real world use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078006/iife-with-unary-operator-real-world-use-case).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have linked to a *question*, not an answer. This is the link you're looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26078333/4751173

You can find these with the 'share' link under each answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Share link worked. (link with hash to my answer was not working) (This link doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078006/iife-with-unary-operator-real-world-use-case/26078333#26078333)

Answer (score 2):

The inconsistency lies in the fact that the pre-populated links are in the question format:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/[questionID]/[title]/[answerID]#[answerID]

rather than the required answer format for user-defined links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/[answerID]/[userID]

so resolving the error via cutting/copying the share link is unintuitive and inconvenient.

Upon submission, the answer format is converted to the question format, so there is no way to see the difference in case you forget for future reference.

Use the following bookmarklet to generate the answer format from the question format:

```
javascript:void(window.prompt('Answer Format: append user ID instead of hash URL', window.location.href.replace(/questions.[0-9]+.[^/]+./,"a/") /* Replace the questions/[questionID]/[title]/ pattern with a/ */ ) )
```

**References**

- [Citation for (linking to) answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316496/1113772)

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks. I remember now the user ID is only useful if you want to get the announcer and other related badges.