# Proper attribution when another answer is better and parts are used in the own answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

Today I answered a question and I'm a bit disappointed about the behaviour of another answerer. I don't know if I remember the timeline exactly but I think it was roughly like that:

- I answered the question and received one upvote and one downvote. The downvote was deserved because it was incorrect.
- I deleted my answer to fix it
- Another person answered using function "A" (just as note: I haven't seen it because I was editing)
- I edited my answer using function "B" and undeleted it.
- The other person changes his answer to use function "B" and says in the *comments* that was because my approach was better but without attributing it in the answer
- I asked him in the comments to attribute at least the idea to my answer and he asked me to come into chat and I explained my reasoning in a bit more detail but he didn't respond.

Functions "A" and "B" are similar but have different applications and the function was only one part of the answer. I'm not jealous that his answer was accepted and upvoted but I feel it's not fair that he didn't even state that part of the idea and solution are taken from my answer.

Is there anything I can do or should I just move on?

I thought about editing his answer myself to attribute my answer but that seems wrong to me.

I don't know if I should link the question in question, I heard it's generally disapproved of because of the meta-effect, so let me know if I should provide it.

Comment: Strongly related: [Citation for (linking to) answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316496/citation-for-linking-to-answers) (disclosure: link also contains an answer showing my free citation extension in the chrome store)

Comment: @TravisJ Does your comment suggest that I should edit the other answer myself including a link? I'm confused... :-)

Comment: I was merely suggesting that if a user uses part of another user's answer, they should cite it, and gave a link to what that citation should look like in printed material. Here is an example where I use it to cite another user's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41515947/1026459 . In your case though, I don't think you should edit the other user's answer primarily because the only part they changed in response to your answer was to change `where` to `argwhere` which in my opinion does not constitute enough of a change to warrant citation.

Comment: That is fairly minor, and while you did point it out first, and probably should have been given more credit for that, sometimes that is just how it works out in the FGITW game going on there. My suggestion would be to move on :)

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestions, I'll move on :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm not jealous that his answer was accepted and upvoted but I feel it's not fair that he didn't even state that part of the idea and solution are taken from my answer.

But he did give you credit, through a comment. While that is arguably not the optimum method of doing so (*), you can't accuse the other answerer of being sneaky and denying you credit. Between that, the fact that the whole situation developed in a span of merely seven minutes, and that the edit summary of the edit that incorporates your solution (which I will assume is neither a lie nor a joke) is...

> Brainfart: I obviously meant argwhere

... I would say no injustice has happened.

Looking at it from a different angle, one might wonder whether the other answerer should have deleted his answer to avoid duplication. Given that the original version his answer was posted just a minute after yours, and that you deleted your answer less than a minute after that, it would seem harsh to demand that from the other answerer -- it would be about as harsh to demand you to, instead of undeleting your answer, suggest `argwhere` in a comment to his answer, which was the only existing answer for a few minutes until you restored your answer.

---

(*): In such cases, I prefer to give credit through a short parenthetical sentence in the answer. For instance, "As shown by MSeifert's answer, [...]", or, if the alternative is clearly better than what I had offered, "MSeifert's answer provides a more convenient solution; still, an alternative is [...]".

Comment: it wasn't too hard to find the question then :-) Thanks for your answer, it makes sense and I haven't read the title of his revision. In my opinion there is a huge difference between attributing in comments or answer because a comment can be deleted without any trace.