# Is there a way to attribute an answer to a different user?

Tags: discussion, reputation

If you look at my profile the most upvoted answer was copy paste from Stack Overflow sister site security.stackexchange.com. I posted a link in the answer. The original answer was upvoted 11 times while my copy/paste post was upvoted 57 times.

Original: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40314/177664

Copy Paste https://stackoverflow.com/a/29137661/4535386

Doesn't [he](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/16228/adi) deserve the reputation?

Comment: No, but someone *else* deserves a bit of extra scrutiny over potential plagiarism...

Comment: @makoto I bumped into the original because I had the same question, I clearly stated in the post that its from there, how would you deal with it?

Comment: Honestly if it were me I probably wouldn't have answered the question with that link.  I'd have left a comment on the original question with a link to that answer instead to maximize the exposure of the answer.

Comment: I would at least credit the other answer in yours. The best case would have been to notify that user and give them time to copy it themselves, but it is acceptable to paste it yourself, even without attribution.

Comment: @makoto if that's the best answer, it should get maximum exposure, don't you agree?

Comment: ...and maximum exposure is indicative of it living on the *other* site.  It isn't like people don't pay attention to comments...

Comment: when you look for a solution, do you take the most upvoted answer or you read through all comments?

Comment: If you were concerned about getting reputation here for someone else's work on another site, you could have marked the answer as community wiki in addition to including the attribution/link in the answer. There's no way to transfer that reputation to the other person, though.

Comment: @Don'tPanic you have a point especially if the post has been viewed 104,893 times.

Comment: [Strongly related: Citation for (linking to) answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316496/citation-for-linking-to-answers)

Comment: If the post gets so many more views and votes here on SO than it gets on Security, maybe the original question should have been asked here as well, as it clearly is more programming related than security related. The way it is now, you don't have to feel guilty about amassing more votes.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303

Comment: You could offer the original author (who is also on SO) a bounty if you want to literally pass them your reputation...

Comment: @TheWanderer It's actually not acceptable to paste it without attribution. All Stack Exchange user contributions are licensed under CC-BY SA 3.0 with **attribution required** (emphasis mine) - that means you have to provide attribution when you paste or use some contribution from anywhere in SE--even elsewhere in SE.

Comment: @Chris_Rands That seems like it could be an abuse of the bounty system to me?

Answer (score 51):

No, but there were two things you should have done (and can still do):

1. Mark your answer as [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), so that you don't gain more* rep from someone else's content; and
2. Make it clearer, using appropriate block quote formatting, that the content is not yours, e.g.:

   > > Make sure you have [OpenSSL support](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php), and you'll never go wrong
   > >     with this one-liner
   > >
   > > ```
   > > $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
   > > ```
   >
   > Source: [*Generating an unguessable token for confirmation
   >   e-mails*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40314)

* *you will still keep any rep you earned prior to the conversion*

Comment: +1. Would additionally recommend also explicitly including the author’s display name and the site it was posted on. Pretty sure this is technically required by the SE reuse license anyway.

Comment: Although I think the citation is perfectly reasonable and necessary - I don't think I agree with the community wiki point. This person has gone to the effort to put this answer in a spot where it is being seen more, and is clearly helping people (judging by the votes). It's cross-site, so duplicate flags won't work (otherwise that would likely be my recommendation). This seems like a pretty reasonable thing to do...

Comment: CW is a tool to indicate that a post is a collaborative work of multiple people, and that others should feel free to make edits to the underlying content of the answer without any thought to the original author's intent.  It's not a way to avoid getting reputation for an answer you've written.  That's just a side effect of the fact that a CW answer is designed to *not have a single author at all* to whom the rep could go to, and no good way of dividing it among the multiple contributors.

Comment: marking as CW now doesn't cancel the previous rep gain on that answer. It just stops it. Well, yes, maybe it's the good move. Whatever, OP was very straightforward bringing that here. thumbs up for that.

Answer (score -2):

It is important to style the material you are quoting using `>`, so it is obvious that the work is not yours.

As for citation, there is an official citation process if you are interested. The Chicago Manual of Style has many different descriptions of how to cite other people's work.

In my opinion, the closest official citation structure for Stack Overflow is the blog style (http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html)

In the example post you list, this format would look like

> Adi, Mon Nov 12 2018, Celeritas, "Generating an unguessable token for confirmation e-mails", Sep 20 '13 at 7:06, https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40314/

I like to reference these citations using a super script in the post, and a subscript at the footer. I edited your post to include the citation, feel free to roll back if you don't think it is inline with your intent.

Comment: Personally I find the official style you've given an example of much less readable than a quick link. Who cares about the two dates, and even the actual URL? The author name is fair enough, as is the title but the rest seems like noise.

Comment: @Shadow It seems like noise until the link breaks and you're trying to find a valid archive.org link in order to fix it. I'll admit I've done a full blown citation either but it'd certainly make fixing URLs easier if we knew when the page was created and when it was visited for the citation.

Comment: @BSMP That would be a fair point, up until the fact that most browsers allow you to right click a link and "copy link address" or similar. The neither hidden nor inaccessible - it's just neatly tucked away until you need it.

Comment: @Shadow How does 'copy link address' help when the address 404s?

Comment: @BSMP isn't that what you would need to in order to use archive.org?

Comment: @Shadow No, you also need a date when the link had the *material you wanted* at that location. You need a tuple (link, date).

Comment: @Shadow - Who cares about the two dates, who cares what you personally find readable? Who knows! This is the official styling. It may be rare on the internet to actually use real citation, but that doesn't make it any less appropriate here. It is placed in the footer as an aside in case anyone wants to have more information.

Comment: Unless you're also going to include citations for what citation format you're using, that citation is utterly confusing. It gives no clue as to what or who "Adi" and "Celeritas" are, nor why there are two dates (in slightly different formats). If you're going to include all that information, you need to include something more than punctuation in between them, e.g. "Answer by Adi on question by Celeritas ...". Within a journal article, or in communication with people who use that style often, a terse but standard format makes sense; but using it outside that context is not a good idea.

Comment: @IMSoP - The slightly different date format was a small mistake from a script generating the citation, so I will give you that. They should be similar. That said, the author of the source and the author of the post may be slightly confusing, that is just part of the adaptation made since Stack Exchange has multiple authors per section on a page. The "Answer by" and "Question by" suggestions are good as well. I think those are good points. Given that those changes are easily possible, I don't think it is valid to call it "not a good idea".

Comment: @TravisJ But at that point, you're not using the standard format any more, so might as well just make up your own. I think "it's useful to have extra information in the citation in case the link goes dead" is useful advice; but "look up a citation style in the Chicago Manual of Style" doesn't really add anything.

Comment: @IMSoP - It is standardized, there are minor edits allowed with the format. Using official citation adds rigor, something I wish more posts at Stack Overflow had.